# fetching float field from SQL Server Database containing NULL Value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I want to fetch float data from sql server database 2008 R2.

In database there are two fields `estimated_amount` and `actual_amount`.

At first only `estimated-amount` filled contains value, and the `actual_amount` field is containing `NULL`.

The problem is that when I fetch data and parse the value it shows error:

> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code   Message=Input
>   string was not in a correct format.   Source=mscorlib

My code is :

```
CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Actual_Amount = float.Parse(Convert.ToString(row["Actual_Amount"]));
```

Please suggest what I can do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write less code and avoid translating to string. You will have to deal with the null separately - Depending on what `row` is, it may support an [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0.aspx)/`IsDBNull` method, so it would be more like:

```
if(row.IsNull("Actual_Amount"))
   CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Actual_Amount = null;
else
   CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Actual_Amount = (float)row["Actual_Amount"];
```

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)

Comment: @user2029240 - Updated the second code snippet to fit in with `row` being a `DataRow`.

Comment: I am not able to assign null to CRM_Doctor_RequestObj.Actual_Amount = null;

Comment: it shows error "cannot convert float to null because its a nonnullable value"

Comment: @user2029240 - Then tell us what value you *do* want to assign if it's `null`. You haven't given us a rule. I'd assumed it was defined as a `float?`, but apparently it's not. Prashant16 seems to have assumed that you want to use `0.0`. But since you've not given us a spec, you can't expect me to post fully working code that matches your spec.

Comment: I am not sure what to assign... I am using this in MVC and I want to display the user that its null in database... not any value at that place... I think I need to take diff field in class for display purpose.

Answer (score 1):

From database select actual_amount like

```
SELECT ISNULL((actual_amount),'0.00') FROM TableName
```

If actual_amount is null then it gives 0.00